# Removing the step numbering from cuisine package

Tags: packages, counters

I would like to remove the step number from the cuisine package. That is the `1` that appears in the left side of the ingredients in the following code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[nonumber]{cuisine}

\begin{document}

\begin{recipe}{Name}{4}{\fr12 hour}

\ing[5]{units}{something}

STEP 1

STEP 2 

...

\end{recipe}

\end{document}
```

I tried to meddle with the package code as well as setting the step number width to 0 with no success. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `xpatch`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[nonumber]{cuisine}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\Displ@ySt@p}{\arabic{st@pnumber}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{recipe}{Name}{4}{\fr12 hour}
\ing[5]{units}{something}

STEP 1

STEP 2

...

\end{recipe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `xpatch` is designed just to avoid cumbersome code like that: `\xpatchcmd{\Displ@ySt@p}{\arabic{st@pnumber}}{}{}{}` should be sufficient. I don't understand why the package uses `\DeclareRobustCommand` for macros that are used in the code for the environment `recipe`. It's just a waste of resources that adds nothing to robustness.

Comment: @egreg Ah yes, thanks for noticing. I forgot to change it back to `\xpatchcmd` after running some tests (at first I was having problems because I was writing `Display` instead of `Displ@y`). I'll update the answer.